# On-demand downloading of vector data for mapsforge

Tags: android, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, mapsforge

I am currently doing a native android application with mapsforge (https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/). I have it working with an offline map for a single country but will later need to have more then one country and this is where I hit the problem.

I want to be able to stream or download parts around me (maybe 10 mile square around me), how would I go about doing this or maybe point me in the direction of material that will help me achieve this

Thanks for the help

Comment: You seem to mix raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) with vector maps. Mapsforge renders vector maps and therefore needs raw vector data. A tile server is only useful for rendering raster tiles which then can be displayed in a browser using OpenLayers or Leaflet.

You should rephrase your question and probably ask about on-demand downloading of vector data for mapsforge.

Comment: Thank you very much, still trying to understand it all as I go along, will rephrase it now

Answer (score 2):

You can generate any vector data square area by specifying the `bbox` argument in the [osmosis](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis) library:

- Download an OpenStreetMap `pbf` file containing the area you're interested in. From [here](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts) or [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html).
- Install osmosis with the [mapsforge map-writer plugin](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md):

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/openstreetmap/osmosis.git
  cd osmosis
  ./gradlew assemble
  mkdir -p ~/.openstreetmap/osmosis/plugins
  cd ~/.openstreetmap/osmosis/plugins
  wget http://ci.mapsforge.org/job/0.5.1/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/mapsforge-map-writer/build/libs/mapsforge-map-writer-0.5.1.jar
  ```
- Create the `.map` vector tiles by specifying the south, west, north, east coordinates in the `bbox` argument:

  ```
  ~/osmosis/package/bin/osmosis --rb file=london_england.osm.pbf --mapfile-writer file=/tmp/london.map bbox=51.38,-0.35,51.67,0.14
  ```